# Does Ref keyword useful for DataTable

Tags: asp.net, datatable, pass-by-reference, reference-type

I read DataTable are of `Reference` type, then does using `ref` keyword make any difference ? Are below two approaches same in terms of performance?

**(1)**

```
public int CalculateValues(DataTable dt)
{
    int output = 0;
    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
          //CalculateValues
    }
    return output;
}
```

**(2)**

```
public int CalculateValues(ref DataTable dt)
{
    int output = 0;
    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
          //CalculateValues
    }
    return output;
}
```

**(1)** vs **(2)** ?

Answer (score 0):

When you pass value type to method, it's do copy your variable, but when you pass reference type it's copy pointer value.
Here is example.

```
public void Change(ReferenceType val)
{
    val = new ReferenceType();
}

public void ChangeRef(ref ReferenceType val)
{
    val = new ReferenceType();
}

void SomeFunction() 
{
    var variable = new ReferenceType();
    var tmp = variable;
    Change(variable); // variable not changed
    Console.WriteLine(variable == tmp); // will print TRUE

    ChangeRef(ref variable); // variable changed
    Console.WriteLine(variable == tmp); // will print FALSE
}
```

So, it's not about performance at all.